# Counting and printing time in java using swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm trying to implement a timer using one thread and print it on a JButton using another thread.
my class for time is like this:

```
public class Time extends Thread 
{
int counter = 0;
public String currentTime = new String();


public String printFormat(int second)
{
    return String.format("%d:%d", second/60, second%60);
}

synchronized public void count(int minute) throws InterruptedException
{
    minute *= 60;
    while(minute >= 0)
    {
        wait(1000);
        minute--;
        currentTime = printFormat(minute);
        System.out.println(currentTime);
    }

}
```

and my main thread is like this:

```
     button.setText(time.currentTime);
```

what is wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: _what is wrong with this piece of code?_ What is it supposd to do?

Comment: It's supposed to print a text which is the timer , on the button ,
Mainly , I want to add a timer to my game.

Comment: It this a requirement, to use two threads? It's easily accomplished using a `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: It is our assignment to use this kind of method , 
but if you can explain it using java swing timer , 
I would appreciate that ;) .

Comment: *what is wrong with this piece of code?* What happens when you run it?

Comment: You may want to post your entire program. It doesn't seem like too long of a program to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"if you can explain it using java swing timer , I would appreciate that"*

If you want to use a `javax.swing.Timer` do the following, it really simple.

- The same way you set a `ActionListener` to a button, you do the same for the timer. Except instead of the button firing the event, it's fired by the timer, every duration period you set for it.
- In the case of a clock like timer, you would set it to 1000,
  indication *do something* every 1000 milliseconds.

In this particular
   example, I just set the text of the button with a count value that I
   increment by one every time the timer event is fired. Heres the `Timer` code

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        count++;
    }
});
timer.start();
```

As you can see it' pretty simple

You can run this example

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class ButtonTimer {

    private JButton button = new JButton(" ");
    private int count = 1;
    public ButtonTimer() {

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                count++;
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ButtonTimer();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you want help trying to figure out your current code, consider posting a runnable program we can test out. So we can see where you're going wrong.

---

Here's a tutorial on [Concurrency With Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: No problem, No problem. If the requirement is using two thread though for the purpose of learning threads, I suggest you learn them.